# Open a file then edit and save file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to edit a `.ini` using codeigniter.

For Now i can open file edit that file but when i save it the file is saved as a **POINTER : RESOURCE ID #5**.

I want to create a new file and i am setting a custom name to that file.

But my code create the file but the file is empty and data i want to write is written in  **POINTER : RESOURCE ID #5**.

What should i be doing?

This is my code:

```
$this->data['parameters']  = parse_ini_file($path.$filename,true);

    while (current($this->data['parameters']) ) 
    {
        $param_set = current($this->data['parameters']);
        $param_type = key($this->data['parameters']);

            foreach ($param_set as $key =>$value) 
            {

                $this->data['parameters'][$param_type][$key] = $this->input->post($key);

            } 

            next($this->data['parameters']);
    }

    $this->load->helper('file');

    $this->load->library('ini');

    $name = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $ext = $this->session->userdata('extension');       

    /*Want to create a new file*/
    $custom_file = fopen('uploads/'.$name.'_'.$ext.'.ini', 'w');

    /* $file returns a file pointer which instead should be the file i just created above*/
    $file = $path.$custom_file;


    $ini = new INI($file);

    $ini->write($file, $this->data['parameters']);
```

> So how to write in the file i created instead of pointer file?